# Como faço para gerar um arquivo excel com os dados obtidos de um webCrawler?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

Estou fazendo um web crawler que deve extrair o nome e o preço dos iphones que aparecem em pesquisa no site da Amazon e gerar um arquivo xlsx com esses dados. No entanto, não estou conseguindo gerar o arquivo xlsx com esses dados.

Estou tentando fazer isso através do modulo excel4node, mas por conta do meu pouco conhecimento estou tendo problemas pra encaixar os dados na planilha.

```
var request = require('request-promise');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var excel = require('excel4node');

var wb = new excel.Workbook();
var ws = wb.addWorksheet('AMAZON');

var url = 'http://localhost:81/index.html';
var newEncode = encodeURI(url);

const crawl ={

    uri: (newEncode),
    transform: function (body){
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }

}

request(crawl)
    .then(($) =>{
        const produtos = []
        $('div[class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28"]').each((i, item)=>{
            const produto = {
                nome: $(item).find('span[class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]').text(),
                preco: $(item).find('span[class="a-price-whole"], span[class="a-price-fraction"], span[class="a-color-base"]').text(),
            }

            // console.log(item);

            ws.cell().string(); //não sei quais parâmetros adicionar aqui

            wb.write('PlanilhaAmazon.xlsx');

        });

    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Comment: Os dados estão chegando corretamente? Preciso saber antes de montar um exemplo

Comment: Sim, Anderson. Os dados estão chegando corretamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De uma olhada no exemplo, primeiro mudei as variaveis globais `var` para `const` evite usar `var`. Depois disso em `ws.cell()`, recebe o primeiro parametro é o número da linha que coloquei o index + 1 e o segundo é a coluna. Em string você coloca o texto que quer escrever.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const excel = require('excel4node');

const wb = new excel.Workbook();
const ws = wb.addWorksheet('AMAZON');

const url = 'http://localhost:81/index.html';
const newEncode = encodeURI(url);

const crawl ={

    uri: (newEncode),
    transform: function (body){
        return cheerio.load(body);
    }

}

request(crawl)
    .then(($) =>{
        const produtos = []
        $('div[class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28"]').each((i, item)=>{
            const produto = {
                nome: $(item).find('span[class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]').text(),
                preco: $(item).find('span[class="a-price-whole"], span[class="a-price-fraction"], span[class="a-color-base"]').text(),
            }

            // console.log(item);

            ws.cell(i + 1, 1).string(produto.nome); //O primeiro parametro é a linha da planilha o segundo é a coluna
            ws.cell(i + 1, 2).string(produto.preco);
            wb.write('PlanilhaAmazon.xlsx');
        });
```

Comment: Deu muito certo! Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Só tem mais uma coisa: você viu que estou fazendo a requisição para o meu servidor local? Então... Era pra eu fazer para o site da Amazon, porém o programa não está aceitando a URL, por algum motivo o programa não me retorna o corpo da página pra fazer a pesquisa, o retorno vem em caracteres aleatórios. Sabe como resolver esse problema????

Comment: Como assim caracteres aleatórios?

Comment: Seu der console.log(body), ao invés de retornar o corpo d requisição feita ele não retorna. Retorna uns caracteres especiais bem aleatórios que não tem no teclado (não sei o nome kkkk)

Comment: É o mesmo código? Só muda a url? ou você modificou algo?

Comment: É o mesmo código. Ele só não está aceitando a url do site

Comment: Pode ser a falta de um cabeçalho durante a requisição. Alguns sites não permitem automação que não sejam por suas APIs, daí, exigem que o cabeçalho da requisição contenha, pelo menos, o user-agent.

Use o JMeter para entender o que pode ser uma requisição válida para um determinado site e, a partir das descobertas, crie o header para a sua requisição.